# Java Eclipse input validation

Tags: java, validation, input, swt, textfield

So here it is: I'm writing a (swt)program.In my form, I have two text fields and a button, but when pressing the button I would like it to validate the (string)text fields. Asking the user for input if nothing in textfields?

Hopefully this question makes sense
Thank you all in Advance!!

Comment: The button has no code yet.

Answer (score 0):

You must do this manually, adding a listern to button.
  If you your TextField is called `textField` and yout Button `button`, it will be something like:

```
\\previous code
button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent(Event e) {
    switch (e.type) {
    case SWT.Selection:
      if(textField.getText() == null || textField.getText().isEmpty()) ; //here you validate
      break;
    }
  }
});
```